# Details View in Asp.net, Set it to NEW

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

I have a grid view on my page, and a hidden details view.
When the user wants to add a new entry, they will click a button, and the gridview will become hidden and the details view will become visible. The only problem is I want my details view to automatically be set empty in the NEW mode, without them having to click the new in the details view form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the RowCommand event of the gridview:

```
myDetailsView.Visible = true;
myDetailsView.CurrentMode = DetailsViewMode.Insert;
myGridView.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

On button click change the mode like:

```
DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert)
```